# Mongo DB can't start, keeps quitting on me

Tags: mongodb, installation, server

I am a total mongo newbie who is very confused, frustrated and frankly lost...

I have tried installing / uninstalling mongo, then reinstalling. AT one point it seemed to be working as I followed a tutorial but ultimately wouldn't after I returned to use it in a node app I am trying to create. Now that I have it installed I created the /data/db but it keeps failing when I go to run "mongod"

---

```
name$ mongod
2015-06-28T15:13:34.503-0400 E NETWORK  [initandlisten] listen(): bind() failed errno:48 Address already in use for socket: 0.0.0.0:27017
2015-06-28T15:13:34.503-0400 E NETWORK  [initandlisten]   addr already in use
2015-06-28T15:13:34.513-0400 I JOURNAL  [initandlisten] journal dir=/data/db/journal
2015-06-28T15:13:34.513-0400 I JOURNAL  [initandlisten] recover : no journal files present, no recovery needed
2015-06-28T15:13:34.541-0400 I JOURNAL  [durability] Durability thread started
2015-06-28T15:13:34.541-0400 I JOURNAL  [journal writer] Journal writer thread started
2015-06-28T15:13:34.541-0400 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] MongoDB starting : pid=4041 port=27017 dbpath=/data/db 64-bit host=Vickens-MBP.home
2015-06-28T15:13:34.541-0400 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] ** WARNING: You are running this process as the root user, which is not recommended.
2015-06-28T15:13:34.541-0400 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] 
2015-06-28T15:13:34.541-0400 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] 
2015-06-28T15:13:34.541-0400 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] ** WARNING: soft rlimits too low. Number of files is 256, should be at least 1000
2015-06-28T15:13:34.542-0400 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] db version v3.0.4
2015-06-28T15:13:34.542-0400 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] git version: nogitversion
2015-06-28T15:13:34.542-0400 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] build info: Darwin yosemitevm.local 14.3.0 Darwin Kernel Version 14.3.0: Mon Mar 23 11:59:05 PDT 2015; root:xnu-2782.20.48~5/RELEASE_X86_64 x86_64 BOOST_LIB_VERSION=1_49
2015-06-28T15:13:34.542-0400 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] allocator: system
2015-06-28T15:13:34.542-0400 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] options: {}
2015-06-28T15:13:34.551-0400 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] now exiting
2015-06-28T15:13:34.551-0400 I NETWORK  [initandlisten] shutdown: going to close listening sockets...
2015-06-28T15:13:34.551-0400 I NETWORK  [initandlisten] shutdown: going to flush diaglog...
2015-06-28T15:13:34.551-0400 I NETWORK  [initandlisten] shutdown: going to close sockets...
2015-06-28T15:13:34.551-0400 I STORAGE  [initandlisten] shutdown: waiting for fs preallocator...
2015-06-28T15:13:34.552-0400 I STORAGE  [initandlisten] shutdown: final commit...
2015-06-28T15:13:34.555-0400 I JOURNAL  [initandlisten] journalCleanup...
2015-06-28T15:13:34.555-0400 I JOURNAL  [initandlisten] removeJournalFiles
2015-06-28T15:13:34.556-0400 I JOURNAL  [initandlisten] Terminating durability thread ...
2015-06-28T15:13:34.663-0400 I JOURNAL  [journal writer] Journal writer thread stopped
2015-06-28T15:13:34.663-0400 I JOURNAL  [durability] Durability thread stopped
2015-06-28T15:13:34.664-0400 I STORAGE  [initandlisten] shutdown: closing all files...
2015-06-28T15:13:34.665-0400 I STORAGE  [initandlisten] closeAllFiles() finished
2015-06-28T15:13:34.665-0400 I STORAGE  [initandlisten] shutdown: removing fs lock...
2015-06-28T15:13:34.665-0400 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] dbexit:  rc: 48
```

Comment: Looks like it's already running or something else is running on that address!

Comment: And how does your comment help the situation? I am looking for help, not a open-ended opinion!

Comment: It's no opinion, those are the only two possibilities. Figure out which.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like something is running on 0.0.0.0:27017,
run command to kill that process first

```
  kill $(lsof -t -i:27017)
```

then start you mongo server

```
sudo rm /var/lib/mongodb/mongod.lock
mongod --repair
sudo service mongodb start
```